# How to move tkinter windows using python after it has been created?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am looking to move a tkinter window to different x and y coordinates after it has been created. For example 5 seconds after the window has been created move it to
x=??? and y=???.

```
 from tkinter import*

root = Tk()
root.title("lol")
root.geometry("300x300")

photo = PhotoImage(file="pepe.gif")
label = Label(image=photo).place(x=10, y=10)

root.mainloop()
```

The above code is just an example, how does it need to be modified to move by itself?

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the geometry?

Comment: Are you aware of the `after` method?

Comment: `root.geometry('+500+300')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example will show you how to reset the root geometry that controls the position of the window on screen; clicking on the image will toggle the locationof the window.

```
from tkinter import *

def move_me(idx=[0]):   # <- creates a closure for the index of the location strings
    loc = ["300x300+200+200", "300x300+300+300"]
    
    root.geometry(loc[idx[0]])   # <-- reset the geometry
    idx[0] = (idx[0]+1) % 2      # <-- toggles the index between 0 and 1

root = Tk()
root.title("lol")
root.geometry("300x300-100+100")

photo = PhotoImage(file="pepe.gif")
button = Button(root, image=photo, command=move_me)
button.place(x=10, y=10)

root.mainloop()
```

---

#### [edit] with auto repeat moving the window.

(attention, you have challenging game to catch the window to close it)

```
from tkinter import *
import random

def move_me():
    x, y = str(random.randrange(800)), str(random.randrange(800))
    loc = "300x300+" + x + '+' + y
    root.geometry(loc)
    root.after(500, move_me)  # <-- auto call to move_me again every 1/2 second

root = Tk()
root.title("lol")
root.geometry("300x300+100+100")

photo = PhotoImage(file="pepe.gif")
label = Label(root, image=photo)
label.place(x=10, y=10)

move_me()      # <-- call to move_me

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks, very helpful. I appreciate the comments, makes it way easier to understand.

Comment: Also, is it possible for it to do it automatically? so that the button does not have to be pressed?

Comment: Yes, I added an example that shows that; I mischievously set the time to half a second, to see if you can catch it... (reset the interpreter if it is too hard, and change the `root.after` parameter to a longer time span)

Comment: haha that's amazing, and I was here messing around with time delays. Thanks again.